# Augmented reality: algorithm for projecting width of object with iPad camera?

Tags: ios, ipad, augmented-reality

In an iPad app, we would like to help users visualize the width of an object with their camera in the style of an augmented reality app.

For instance, if we want to help someone visualize the width of a bookshelf against a wall, how could we do that? Are there algorithms to estimate width (i.e., if you're standing 5 feet away and pointing your camera at the wall, 200 pixels in the camera will represent X inches)?

Any good resources to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you may wish to do a bit of research yourself as this will vary depending upon the camera being used, resolution and it's depth of field.

I would recommend taking a large strip of paper (wallpaper would work fine) and writing measurements at specified intervals, e.g. you could write distance markers for each foot on the paper. Then all you need to do is stand at varying distances from the wall with the paper mounted to it, and take photographs, you should then be able to establish the correlation of how distance, resolution and measurements correlate to each other and use these findings to form your own algorithm. You've essentially answered your own question.